# Magento 2.4.1 Move Out of Stock In last Of Category Listing

Tags: module, event-observer, magento2.4, plugin, stock

I want to move **out of stock product** in last of the category listing, itried below code but same seems not working.

**app/code/Meetanshi/StockQuantity/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Meetanshi_StockQuantity" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Meetanshi/StockQuantity/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
       <observer name="stockLast" instance="Meetanshi\StockQuantity\Observer\StockLast" />
   </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Meetanshi/StockQuantity/Observer/StockLast.php**

```
<?php
namespace Meetanshi\StockQuantity\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as CoreToolbar;
class StockLast implements ObserverInterface
{
   protected $scopeConfig;
   protected $_storeManager;
   protected $coreToolbar;
   public function __construct(
       ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
       StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       CoreToolbar $toolbar
   )
   {
       $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->coreToolbar = $toolbar;
   }
   public function execute(Observer $observer)
   {
       $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getData('collection');
       try {
           $websiteId = 0;
           $stockId = 'stock_id';
           $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
               array('_inv' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_status')),
               "_inv.product_id = e.entity_id and _inv.website_id=$websiteId",
               array('stock_status')
           );
           $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('in_stock', 'IFNULL(_inv.stock_status,0)', array());
           $collection->getSelect()->reset('order');
           $collection->getSelect()->order('in_stock DESC');
           //code for Filter Price Low to High or High to Low with stock filter.
           if ($this->coreToolbar->getCurrentOrder() == 'price') {
               $direction = $this->coreToolbar->getCurrentDirection();
               $collection->getSelect()->order("min_price $direction");
           }
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
       }
       return $this;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't use the new ui_component for grid?

Comment: I tested this code it seems to work, at least as far as generating a SQL query that includes the expected sorting. Perhaps you could provide more specific details about how it is not working for you?

Comment: @jiheison have u checked in magento 2.4.x

Comment: @user1799722 good question! I forgot that the project I was working on at the time was 2.3.x. It does not work in a 2.4.x site. Sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: I tried implementing the code in a plugin for Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct that provided an afterGetLoadedProductCollection method. That allowed me to modify the collection query as expected, but the actual product list did not render accordingly. In the collection class, Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection, there is a note: "This collection should be refactored to not have dependencies on MySQL-specific implementation." Maybe this is why modifying the SQL query does not work, i.e. the query is maintained as a legacy, but isn't used for the search? Odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you cannot use the code above to apply to magento 2.4.x because Magento 2.4.x used ElasticSearch as default search engine.

Here I've created a sample module for your purpose

https://github.com/tuyennn/magento2-outofstockatlast

Hope this help.

Comment: i tested but it seems not working for me

Comment: Reindexing after you enable the module, see README.md

Comment: reindexing already done

Comment: @user1799722 Not sure but for me, all seem to be working fine

Comment: @TuyenNguyen:  I'm getting below error using your module. Do you have any suggestions

{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [out_of_stock_at_last] in order to sort on

Note: Your module works well in Vanilla Magento2. I'm facing issue in one of my project

Comment: @TuyenNguyen: After reindex issue is resolved.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen  Products are not loading issue with sort order options 'Price - High To Low' and 'Price - Low To High', please help

Comment: For those who have problems after the 2.4.5 upgrade this module might help: https://github.com/plumrocket/module-layered-navigation-fix-magento-2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 move out of stock products to the end of category page, this solution is Elasticsearch base, suitable for 2.4.x versions.
https://github.com/majidiyan/magento2-out-of-stock-move-end-category