# How to display out of stock products at the end of the catalog in MSI Magento 2.4.2

Tags: plugin

I want to display out of stock products at the end of the category page of Magento 2.4.2. i have msi implemented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2.4.1 Move Out of Stock In last Of Category Listing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/335061/magento-2-4-1-move-out-of-stock-in-last-of-category-listing)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question. [Magento 2.4.1 Move Out of Stock In last Of Category Listing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/335061/magento-2-4-1-move-out-of-stock-in-last-of-category-listing).

And this module by Tuyen Nguyen helped me with putting out of stock products to end of category pages. https://github.com/tuyennn/magento2-outofstockatlast

Check out this module. It works for Magento 2.4.x and above using, MSI and elasticsearch.